# May not = can not, not allowed or prohibited?

Tags: modal-verbs

I did an English test and there was a question which made me really confused.

You **may not** take this trip.

In the sentence above, **may not** can be substituted by:

1. You **are prohibited to** take this trip
2. You **are not allowed to** take this trip
3. You **can not** take this trip

Which one is the right answer: 1, 2 or 3?

Thank you!

Comment: "May" and "can" have been a problem since forever.  Certainly in informal communications they are roughly equivalent, with "may" being a bit more polite.  About all one can say with much certainty is that it's rare to do much canning in May.

Comment: The auxiliary *may* can suggest potential ("You may have won something") or permission ("You may not leave your boots in the hall"). The problem is, the term is somewhat ambiguous, e.g., "He may not attend the party" can be used in either sense.

Comment: That's a stupid test question because the meaning of the sentence changes depending on context and tone. 1, 2, and 3 are all correct. And 1 and 2 are identical in meaning.

Comment: **Can not** means something quite different than **cannot**. I can't tell if you're confusing the two or not. Of the three sentences in the question, however, only the second looks typical to me. The third is syntactical, but I don't think it means what's intended. And the first is altogether wrong with the use of *prohibited* ***to take***.

Comment: Also, "prohibited from taking", not "prohibited to take". The problem with tests is that a great many of them are simply badly written.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this test was written by someone who doesn't know English very well. "can be substitute for" should be "can be **a** substitute for"

Comment: Of the thee, #3 preserves the ambiguous wording best. However, maybe there’s a #4 “none of the above” - textually replacing the two words “may not” with a whole sentence produces a mess.

Comment: The bottom line is that English modals like may, can, should, are used in multiple ways. 'You may not take this trip' either means 'You are barred from taking this trip' or 'There is a possibility that you won't actually take this trip'. Of the answers provided, (1) is ungrammatical, and (3) is a rarefied way of saying 'You are not compelled to take this trip'. (As mentioned above, '_can not_' and '_cannot_ or _can't_' are quite different; also, 'you can ...' is often used conversationally for 'you are allowed to'.) So only (2) is available.